# android studio cant build

Tags: android, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\SETIAWAN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat": 
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with -- info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 12.109 secs
```

Anyone can help. When I try to run dx.bat. Error Windows can't find this file(dx.bat)

Answer (score 1):

You may adding android-support-v4.jar for multiple times. Remove the dependencies of android-support-v4.jar from project's `build.gradle` and just have a single dependencies, such that:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: I don't added android-support-v4.jar. Just have a single dependencies like that