# android studio cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I try to run my android application, I receive an error message in the run message log.

```
I/O Error: D:\Apps\Application\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\app.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I don't believe this is a coding error because android studio is not telling me that there are errors within my java classes or xml layouts, but if you do want code, please comment so. I think the error is in the gradle dependencies. Can anyone explain how to solve this issue?

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Note: I have googled this error, but the only one who has also had this issue is this person ([android studio cant build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038595/android-studio-cant-build)) but the answer doesn't apply to me.

Comment: Try to rename the apk to the name what error shown under build/output/apk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to close project, remove folder `classes` on path `D:\Apps\Application\app\build\intermediates\classes\`, reopen project and rebuild. When I had same issue, it helped me.

Comment: I deleted build folders, rebuilt, closed and re-opened the project.  Nothing helps.