# Android : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android app now won't run. This is after I cancelled a build that was in progress.

Error:

```
I/O Error: D:\***\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\app.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

How can I get back to having my app running successfully? Thank you all in advance.

---

UPDATE:
Cleaning and building doens't help at all

Comment: This link might help u [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839167/android-studio-cannot-find-the-file-specified][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839167/android-studio-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Bin & Gen folder and re-run the App. In case still not working then restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the project first, then remove folder classes on path

> D:***\app\build\intermediates\classes\

After that reopen project and rebuild.