# android studio cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ioexception

I installed (again) Android studio 1.0.1. I am using Windows 8.1 Pro now and installed Java x64, I also did set up `JAVA_HOME` EV to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31` and Android studio is installed in `F:\ANDROID\android-sdk`  When I try to run my project I get the Following Error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "F:\ANDROID\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Check https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79954 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038595/android-studio-cant-build

Comment: Hey thanks for advice. i formatted my laptop and again installed Android studio and now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer but Resolved that issue after formatted my laptop (Windows) because reinstalling Android studio did not resolved my problem.
You can try to **update Android SDK** otherwise last option **format your laptop after taking back-up**.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem, I formatted my Laptop (Windows) and installed Android Studio again. I Also found that It was Android SDK problem.
If you are facing same problem , you can update your Android SDK.
I hope it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Resolved that issue after formatted my laptop because reinstalling Android studio was not resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem since I updated the android studio from version 1.5 to version 2.1. But I uninstalled this version and I installed again version 1.5. After this, the problem is solved. Maybe you can use thus option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Resolved that issue after formatted my laptop because reinstalling Android studio was not resolved my problem.